# Are Subversion commits atomic?

Tags: svn, commit, atomic

Are commits performed by Subversion atomic?

What will happen if commit failed?

Are there some files committed successfully while some failed?
If so, what could i do to go back to the correct state?

Comment: Did you take a look at the SVN documentation?

Comment: not all of the document.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, commits are atomic — here's a [citation from "The Subversion book"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.revs):

> A Subversion client commits (that is, communicates the changes made
>   to) any number of files and directories as a single atomic
>   transaction. By atomic transaction, we mean simply this: either all of
>   the changes are accepted into the repository, or none of them is.
>   Subversion tries to retain this atomicity in the face of program
>   crashes, system crashes, network problems, and other users' actions.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there some files committed successfully while some failed? If so,
>   what could i do to go back to the correct state?

No, this cannot happen by design. Commits in Apache Subversion are atomic.